# Calling arrays from a dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have a .mat file loaded in with scipy.io loadmat() which has taken all of my binary data from Matlab and turned it into concatenated arrays. The problem is that I need to call 4 out of 43 of these arrays and assign them to specific variables like speed and aziumth.

Comment: Showing an example of you concatenated arrays and your expected results would really help you get a better answer.

Comment: If your concat_arrays looks something like this `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8]]`, you can just splice out the first 4 of the inner ones by assignment like this: `a,b,c,d = concat_arrays[:4]`. You get the idea for any other index. Of course, we'd need to know how exactly they are concatenated and what data structure they are nested in.

Comment: :/ it says invalid syntax.... my data is in arrays like this only MUCH longer. I don't know if that helps.[[(([[139.92897657],
       [139.9582408 ],
       [140.41169849]]))]]